# Accordion 'Hop' Glitch

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I don't know how best to describe this issue, so here's an attached gif.
Basically, I have an accordion list which only allows one item to be expanded at a time. But, when clicking on a new item to expand, the lower items 'hop' up, as if the expanding and collapsing items are going at different speeds.
The thing that confuses me is I did not always have this issue. It seemed to start up for no apparent reason. I have tried removing margins and padding, and setting `max` and `min` height to `none` for all relevant divs involved. I have tried different transition speeds (although I cannot figure out how to make transition speeds different per `collapse` vs `expand`).

For reference, the header and the collapsible `div` are siblings, and the header has an `a` tag that looks like this:

```
<a class="esp-list-icon collapsed" data-target="#collapseSiblingId" data-parent="#parentContainer" data-toggle="collapse">
```

Honestly, I can live with the little 'hop', but it's just something that's bugging me, especially since I did not always have the issue.

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/rbu70zeg/ This Fiddle is essentially the same, but does not have the issue I am describing. I am not sure how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Please add enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: One second. Trying to figure out JSFiddle.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). JsFiddle links don't count as an MCVE. Without an MCVE **in your question**, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @zero298 https://jsfiddle.net/rbu70zeg/ Okay so... This fiddle doesn't have the issue I'm describing, even though as far as I can tell it is structurally identical.

Comment: Now I'm annoyed with myself. In my actual code, the p tag had padding I didn't take care of. That's what was causing the issue.

Comment: @TimMorris Don't feel bad.  Accidentally solving your own issue is one of the intended side effects of creating an MCVE.  If you can, try to get it so that the minimal code you posted **can** reproduce the issue so that others can understand what the issue was and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a paragraph tag in my code which had implicit padding, thus causing the issue with the accordion, and thus why the fiddle didn't have the issue. Thanks anyone who gave this a look-over, anyway!